# Converting List<MyClass> to List<MyClass.Mydata> in C#

Tags: c#

Let's assume I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list of this class:

```
List<MyClass>
```

and I want to make a:

```
List<string>
```

which will contain all MyClass.Name from:

```
List<MyClass>
```

Is there a fast way how to do that using Linq for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) and `ToList`:

```
List<string> nameList = list.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Another, non-LINQ, way is to use [`List.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<string> nameList = list.ConvertAll(x => x.Name);
```

This is slightly more efficient because it knows the size of the target list beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was missing.

Comment: @JosefKvita, don't forget to accept the answer, this and upvote is how you say "thanks" on SO.

Answer (score 3):

That is very trivial, you just need a `Select()` and then materialize the result in a `List<T>` using `ToList()` :

```
List<string> result = list.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of type conversions in your code (e.g. from entity model to DTOs), take a look at [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). This allows you to have all mapping definitions in a central location. It also can convert objects by convention.

```
using AutoMapper;

// only set up once in mapping config
CreateMap<MyClass, string>().ConvertUsing(src => src.Name); 

// usage
var myClass = new MyClass { Name = "the name" };
string result = Mapper.Map<string>(myClass);
```

It can resolve collections out of the box by applying the known mappings to each member.

```
MyClass[] myClassArray = new [] { myClass1, myClass2 };
string[] result = Mapper.Map<string[]>(myClassArray);
```